# How to merge multiple pdf files from list box

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext, windows-forms-designer

I have a program that selects from two paths and merges those pdf files to a C: location in a merge folder. I want to instead merge multiple pdf files that are in the list box. I changed the buttons to only one path so I will add multiple files to the list box. I am trying to find out how to make my program read from the listbox instead of reading from the textbox, and merging multiple pdfs instead of just two.

I removed the second line to where it ask for the second file and I created a listbox that will show the multiple files after adding it from the select file button.

```
namespace mergePdf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Merge Folder\"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Merge Folder\");
            string pdfFile1 = Path.GetFullPath(textBoxPdfFile1Path.Text);


            string[] filenames = { pdfFile1 };
            string outputFileName = "Merge.pdf";
            string outputPath = @"C:\Merge Folder\" + outputFileName;
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(doc, new FileStream(outputPath, 
            FileMode.Create));
            if (writer == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            doc.Open();
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
                reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 
                    i);
                    writer.AddPage(page);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

            writer.Close();
            doc.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputPath);
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxPdfFile1Path.Text = 
            System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, 
            @"C:\Users\jesse\Downloads");


        }

        protected void btnSelectFile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxPdfFile1Path.Text = ofd.FileName;
                string[] files = ofd.FileNames;
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the ListBox [items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_Items)?

Comment: Right now these files are being merged by whats being entered in the textbox, i want these files to be merged from whats being sent to the listbox after browsing for the files and adding them to the listbox. I hope this makes sense.